# Can Cordova publish mobile application using HTML5+KendoUI Mobile with Web API

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, asp.net-web-api, kendo-mobile

I have a plan to build mobile application using HTML5+KendoUI Mobile with Web API but i'm not sure Cordova can publish this app with Web API or not.

Does anyone have experience on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quoc,
Web API is used to write APIs which resides on the server. Your mobile app will contain only Kendo JS, HTML and CSS files. This mobile app residing on PhoneGap talks to Web API hosted on your servers. I have written a book titled "Building Mobile Applications Using Kendo UI Mobile and ASP.NET Web API " on this topic which is available here: [http://www.amazon.com/Building-Mobile-Applications-Using-ASP-NET/dp/1782160922](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782160922)

Comment: hi @Whizkid747 
I bought this book via Packtpup, it's good  resource to start developing mobile hybrid app but still lack of some article as i desire like as deploying a real app by Cordova (Icenium), WebAPI OData...
btw, did you publish any app by this technique into AppStore?

Comment: Hi, The book focuses only on development. deployment is a different ball game altogether. For publishing your app, you should look in to Icenium or PhoneGap build(https://build.phonegap.com/). These tools takes ur HTML, JS and CSS, package it using Cordova and provide you with .apk, .ipa files. To generate these files, all you need will be certificates from apple and google for iOS and android respectively.